# What does this code snippet in PHP source mean?

Tags: php, c

```
PHP_FE(serialize, arginfo_serialize)
PHP_FE(unserialize, arginfo_unserialize)
```

Anyone knows where `arginfo_serialize` is defined?

I've searched the entire project but can't find the symbols of `arginfo_serialize`...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's defined via macro in [ext/standard/basic_functions.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/basic_functions.c?revision=304705&view=markup#l2643).

Comment: @yoyo: Of course not. It's in the `ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO`, `ZEND_ARG_INFO`, and `ZEND_END_ARG_INFO` macros.

Comment: Did you find how actually `serialize()` is implemented in PHP?